# Display only the posts which have a specific value (custom field)

Tags: wordpress

I added a custom field "accueil" in the posts, i want to display the posts which have the value 1 of the custom field "accueil" . By default his value is 0 .

functions.php

```
add_action('wp_insert_post', 'wpc_champs_personnalises_defaut');
 function wpc_champs_personnalises_defaut($post_id)
 {
 if ( $_GET['post_type'] != 'page' ) {
 add_post_meta($post_id, 'accueil', '0', true);
 }
 return true;
 }
```

in my pages, i have a variable ars when i might put a condition which will be if the post has the custom field "accueil" which has the value 1.

this is the beginning of my code :

```
// POSTS RECENT
    $args = wp_get_post_meta('accueil' => '1' );
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
    $category = get_the_category( $recent_posts );
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
```

I tried to use get post meta but it doesn't work, what is the good code ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make use of the `WP_Query` class. For example:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'meta_key' => 'accueil', 'meta_value' => '1' ) );

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        // Echo something.
    }

} else {
    // No posts found
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Thanks it works, it's exactly what i wanted :) thanks